# How to click on ok on remote machine while starting machine by using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, remote-debugging, remote-access, remote-desktop, qtp

I am connecting to Remote machine successfully by using below VBScript But the problem is it is stopping at OK button. If once I click on ok Manually then machine is opening.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set cloner = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

cloner.run"mstsc"

'run remote desktop connection

WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"DV01234"

cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"password"

cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 1000

'cloner.run"cmd"
```

CAN ANY ONE HELP ME HOW TO CLICK OK BY USING VB SCRIPT ?

Comment: WARNING : UNAUTHORISED ACCESS IS PROHIBITED

Authorised users are bound by the Computer User Agreement.It is your responsibility to agree and adhere to its regulations. You must also compoly with the
Data Protection Policy. You can read the agreement after logging on by double clicking on ect......


Then OK button appear right.. This one I have to click by VB Script

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UFT 11.50 (UFT is the new name for QTP) you can use [Insight](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/6355855) in order to use image based identification to identify the **OK** button and click on it.